# Python: How to add a filter to a histogram

Tags: python, powerbi, filtering, histogram

I use Python in Power BI and have currently the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(dataset.age, bins=10, edgecolor="#6A9662", color="#DDFFDD", alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

In my table i have a column TYPE with "E" and "G". How can i add a Filter TYPE = "E" to the Python code?

Many thanks in advance!

I am expecting that my histogram shows only results for the filtered table TYPE = "E".

Comment: Sorry didnt know. I am new here. I caught up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to filter the dataframe before plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = dataset[dataset["TYPE"]=="E"].age
plt.hist(data, bins=10, edgecolor="#6A9662", color="#DDFFDD", alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter your data before feeding it to the hist function. For example, if your original data set resides in a CSV-file containing

| Name | Age | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | 1 | E |
| Car2 | 5 | G |
| Car3 | 9 | G |
| Car4 | 2 | E |
| Car5 | 8 | E |
| Car6 | 6 | G |
| Car7 | 9 | E |
| Car8 | 3 | G |
| Car9 | 5 | G |
| Car10 | 7 | G |
| Car11 | 2 | E |

you can process it with the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# read data from the CSV file
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", delimiter="\t")

# filter type E data
dataset_type_e = dataset[dataset["Type"] == "E"]

plt.hist(dataset_type_e["Age"], bins=10, edgecolor="#6A9662", color="#DDFFDD", alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

This is what I got as a result:

[image]

The type E data could be also filtered like this:

```py
age_type_e = [e for e, t in zip(dataset["Age"], dataset["Type"]) if t == "E"]
```

which is a longer piece of code, but it seems to be more general and could be easily adapted to work with any other kind of data, not only pandas data frames.